Is it true that Bhagwan Shiva fulfills the wishes of people quickly?
I have seen countless number of claiming that Bhagwan Shiva fulfills their wishes when they started praying to them.
Is it true that he fulfills the wishes quickly ?
Is praying in sanskrit essential ?
Does he fulfill the wishes of 100 % of all people ?

A name of Bhagavana Shiva is Aśutoṣa - 'He who is pleased quickly', which might explain some things regarding your query.

This question is similar to: Which Scriptures say Shiva is easily pleased than rest of Gods?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
